# spring-boot:build-image gets stuck

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-native

I want to test the new native-build feature of the spring boot 3.0 release. I am following this tutorial [here][1].

I installed jdk java 22.3.r17-nik via sdkman.
I ran `$ mvn -Pnative spring-boot:build-image`. The process starts but then always get stuck.

This is the log:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.example:myproject >------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.0:build-image (default-cli) > package @ myproject >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/klaaspelzer/Projects/boot3/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ myproject ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/klaaspelzer/Projects/boot3/target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.0:build-image (default-cli) < package @ myproject <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.0:build-image (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Building image 'docker.io/library/myproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled builder image 'paketobuildpacks/builder@sha256:850b2b3dd3eab7bacfe33839712c67c3cb50431aff4ff36c435b3d97ea927268'
[INFO]  > Pulling run image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run:tiny-cnb' 100%
[INFO]  > Pulled run image 'paketobuildpacks/run@sha256:c6b81e85b32036dab113dc33454eaa29c006c252bb48a87bf623a635c1763ce6'
[INFO]  > Executing lifecycle version v0.15.1
[INFO]  > Using build cache volume 'pack-cache-eed8708d57f5.build'
[INFO] 
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> ANALYZING
[INFO]     [creator]     Previous image with name "docker.io/library/myproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" not found
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     6 of 14 buildpacks participating
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates   3.5.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica 9.10.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/syft              1.22.1
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar    6.5.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot       5.20.0
[INFO]     [creator]     paketo-buildpacks/native-image      5.6.0
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> RESTORING
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> BUILDING
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for CA Certificates 3.5.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Helper: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Creating /layers/paketo-buildpacks_ca-certificates/helper/exec.d/ca-certificates-helper
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for BellSoft Liberica 9.10.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ARGS           --no-man-pages --no-header-files --strip-debug --compress=1  configure custom link arguments (--output must be omitted)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_JLINK_ENABLED        false                                                        enables running jlink tool to generate custom JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_TYPE                 JRE                                                          the JVM type - JDK or JRE
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_JVM_VERSION              11                                                           the Java version
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_ENABLED           false                                                        enables Java remote debugging support
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_PORT              8000                                                         configure the remote debugging port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_DEBUG_SUSPEND           false                                                        configure whether to suspend execution until a debugger has attached
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_HEAP_DUMP_PATH                                                                       write heap dumps on error to this path
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_ENABLED        true                                                         enables Java Native Memory Tracking (NMT)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JAVA_NMT_LEVEL          summary                                                      configure level of NMT, summary or detail
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ARGS                                                                             configure custom Java Flight Recording (JFR) arguments
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JFR_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Flight Recording (JFR)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_ENABLED             false                                                        enables Java Management Extensions (JMX)
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JMX_PORT                5000                                                         configure the JMX port
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_HEAD_ROOM           0                                                            the headroom in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_LOADED_CLASS_COUNT  35% of classes                                               the number of loaded classes in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_JVM_THREAD_COUNT        250                                                          the number of threads in memory calculation
[INFO]     [creator]         $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS                                                                        the JVM launch flags
[INFO]     [creator]         Using Java version 17 extracted from MANIFEST.MF
[INFO]     [creator]       BellSoft Liberica NIK 17.0.5: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://download.bell-sw.com/vm/22.3.0/bellsoft-liberica-vm-core-openjdk17.0.5+8-22.3.0+2-linux-amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]         Verifying checksum
[INFO]     [creator]         Expanding to /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/native-image-svm
[INFO]     [creator]         Adding 127 container CA certificates to JVM truststore
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/JAVA_HOME.override
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/JDK_HOME.override
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Syft 1.22.1
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/syft
[INFO]     [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/anchore/syft/releases/download/v0.60.3/syft_0.60.3_linux_amd64.tar.gz
[INFO]     [creator]         Verifying checksum
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/SYFT_CHECK_FOR_APP_UPDATE.default
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Executable JAR 6.5.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/executable-jar
[INFO]     [creator]       Class Path: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.delim
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.prepend
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Spring Boot 5.20.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED   false  whether to contribute Spring Boot cloud bindings support
[INFO]     [creator]       Launch Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_DISABLED  false  whether to auto-configure Spring Boot environment properties from bindings
[INFO]     [creator]         $BPL_SPRING_CLOUD_BINDINGS_ENABLED   true   Deprecated - whether to auto-configure Spring Boot environment properties from bindings
[INFO]     [creator]       Class Path: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.append
[INFO]     [creator]         Writing env.build/CLASSPATH.delim
[INFO]     [creator]       Image labels:
[INFO]     [creator]         org.opencontainers.image.title
[INFO]     [creator]         org.opencontainers.image.version
[INFO]     [creator]         org.springframework.boot.version
[INFO]     [creator]     Warning: BOM table is deprecated in this buildpack api version, though it remains supported for backwards compatibility. Buildpack authors should write BOM information to <layer>.sbom.<ext>, launch.sbom.<ext>, or build.sbom.<ext>.
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Native Image 5.6.0
[INFO]     [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/native-image
[INFO]     [creator]       Build Configuration:
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_BINARY_COMPRESSION_METHOD                Compression mechanism used to reduce binary size. Options: `none` (default), `upx` or `gzexe`
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_NATIVE_IMAGE                       true  enable native image build
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS             arguments to pass to the native-image command
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS_FILE        a file with arguments to pass to the native-image command
[INFO]     [creator]         $BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILT_ARTIFACT              the built application artifact explicitly, required if building from a JAR
[INFO]     [creator]       Native Image: Contributing to layer
[INFO]     [creator]         Executing native-image -H:+StaticExecutableWithDynamicLibC -H:Name=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/com.example.boot3.MyApplication -cp /workspace:/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.4.5.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-core-1.4.5.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-to-slf4j-2.19.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.19.0.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-2.0.4.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-6.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-jcl-6.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.14.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.1.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-web-6.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-observation-1.10.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/micrometer-commons-1.10.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-context-6.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-expression-6.0.2.jar:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-jarmode-layertools-3.0.0.jar com.example.boot3.MyApplication
[INFO]     [creator]     ================================================================================
[INFO]     [creator]     GraalVM Native Image: Generating '/layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/com.example.boot3.MyApplication' (static executable)...
[INFO]     [creator]     ================================================================================
[INFO]     [creator]     [1/7] Initializing...                                           (39.3s @ 0.16GB)
[INFO]     [creator]      Version info: 'GraalVM 22.3.0 Java 17 CE'
[INFO]     [creator]      Java version info: '17.0.5+8-LTS'
[INFO]     [creator]      C compiler: gcc (linux, x86_64, 7.5.0)
[INFO]     [creator]      Garbage collector: Serial GC
[INFO]     [creator]      1 user-specific feature(s)
[INFO]     [creator]      - org.springframework.aot.nativex.feature.PreComputeFieldFeature
[INFO]     [creator]     The bundle named: org.apache.el.Messages, has not been found. If the bundle is part of a module, verify the bundle name is a fully qualified class name. Otherwise verify the bundle path is accessible in the classpath.
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     === Image generator watchdog detected no activity. This can be a sign of a deadlock during image building. Dumping all stack traces. Current time: Thu Nov 24 21:38:08 UTC 2022
```

I ran it multiple times and updated docker. I am using a macbook pro with m1 chip.
Docker is allowed to use 10 GB and 5 cores but is barely using 300mb RAM.

my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

my main:

```
package com.example.boot3;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

EDIT:

I reinstalled docker, now the process went further but stuck again.
New logs:

```
[INFO]     [creator]     [1/7] Initializing...                                           (39.7s @ 0.16GB)
[INFO]     [creator]      Version info: 'GraalVM 22.3.0 Java 17 CE'
[INFO]     [creator]      Java version info: '17.0.5+8-LTS'
[INFO]     [creator]      C compiler: gcc (linux, x86_64, 7.5.0)
[INFO]     [creator]      Garbage collector: Serial GC
[INFO]     [creator]      1 user-specific feature(s)
[INFO]     [creator]      - org.springframework.aot.nativex.feature.PreComputeFieldFeature
[INFO]     [creator]     The bundle named: org.apache.el.Messages, has not been found. If the bundle is part of a module, verify the bundle name is a fully qualified class name. Otherwise verify the bundle path is accessible in the classpath.
[INFO]     [creator]     Field org.springframework.core.NativeDetector#imageCode set to true at build time
[INFO]     [creator]     Field org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter#log4jSpiPresent set to true at build time
[INFO]     [creator]     Field org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter#log4jSlf4jProviderPresent set to true at build time
[INFO]     [creator]     Field org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter#slf4jSpiPresent set to true at build time
[INFO]     [creator]     Field org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter#slf4jApiPresent set to true at build time
[INFO]     [creator]     Field org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService#jsr354Present set to false at build time
[INFO]     [creator]     Field org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector#kotlinPresent set to false at build time
[INFO]     [creator]     Field org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector#kotlinReflectPresent set to false at build time
[INFO]     [creator]     Field org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator#imageCode set to true at build time
[INFO]     [creator]     [2/7] Performing analysis...  [**********]                     (337.7s @ 1.82GB)
[INFO]     [creator]       10,223 (89.53%) of 11,418 classes reachable
[INFO]     [creator]       16,614 (63.36%) of 26,220 fields reachable
[INFO]     [creator]       48,428 (58.34%) of 83,017 methods reachable
[INFO]     [creator]          466 classes,   138 fields, and 2,281 methods registered for reflection
[INFO]     [creator]           63 classes,    68 fields, and    55 methods registered for JNI access
[INFO]     [creator]            4 native libraries: dl, pthread, rt, z
[INFO]     [creator]     [3/7] Building universe...                                      (26.5s @ 2.12GB)
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Warning: Dynamic proxy method java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance invoked at org.springframework.core.annotation.SynthesizedMergedAnnotationInvocationHandler.createProxy(SynthesizedMergedAnnotationInvocationHandler.java:304)
[INFO]     [creator]     Warning: Dynamic proxy method java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance invoked at org.springframework.core.io.support.VfsPatternUtils.visit(VfsPatternUtils.java:51)
[INFO]     [creator]     Warning: Dynamic proxy method java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance invoked at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils.resolveAutowiringValue(AutowireUtils.java:134)
[INFO]     [creator]     Warning: Aborting stand-alone image build due to dynamic proxy use without configuration.
[INFO]     [creator]     Warning: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
[INFO]     [creator]     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]     [creator]         12.8s (3.1% of total time) in 29 GCs | Peak RSS: 3.50GB | CPU load: 3.38
[INFO]     [creator]     ================================================================================
[INFO]     [creator]     Failed generating '/layers/paketo-buildpacks_native-image/native-image/com.example.boot3.MyApplication' after 6m 46s.
[INFO]     [creator]     Generating fallback image...
```

It says it failed to generating the image. Weird?
[1]: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image

Comment: this looks like docker configuration problem. if you want to test without docker run **mvn -Pnative native:compile** and run the executable from target folder.

Comment: I tried but now I get the error, that I have to specify the main class. Shouldn't spring provide this information?
Error: `Error: Please specify class (or <module>/<mainclass>) containing the main entry point method. (see --help)`

Comment: it does, I think your pom is not in good condition. try https://start.spring.io/ create a demo project with graal dependency and try same command, that was working in my local :)

Comment: It's working now :)! The spring maven build plugin was missing. I can use now native executeables. Any tipps on the image build? Which command are u using?

Comment: I dont really use docker images much, but if I was I would go with **spring-boot:build-image** probably they are fallowing every standards :)